# Show to wait popup when page loads in the masterpage?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, sharepoint

I have link in the master page in sharepoint. when the user clicks on that link It is taking ages to load the page. I want open a popup (jquery will be good) to show and when ever pages popup should disapper.

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderGlobalNavigation" runat="server">
    <map name="Map">
        <area shape="rect" coords="225,16,287,33" href="/_layouts/MyAlerts.aspx" 
        alt="My Alerts">
    </map>
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

How can we handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know,
u can show the loading image by using CSS.
After u complete load, then u swap back to ur desired control.
[Here is an excellent example. by **Dave Ward**](http://encosia.com/2008/02/05/boost-aspnet-performance-with-deferred-content-loading/)

Answer (score 0):

you would have to alter the MyAlerts.aspx page to show the popup/"loading" message and load the portion of the page that was taking a long time through an ajax call. when the success handler is called you can swap out the loading message for the content.